# Expo notifications not working when channel id is used

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-notifications

I am using the following code to create two channels for my expo react app, on Android:

```
Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
            name: "default",
            importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
            vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
            lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
        })  

Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("gameupdates", {
                name: "gameupdates",
                importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
                vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
                lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
            })
```

The channel is successfully created and I can even find it when I go into the Expo app notification options.

When I send a notification using [expo's tool](https://expo.io/notifications) without any channel id, it works fine. However, when I use the channel id "gameupdates", the notification never reaches my phone.

Any idea why?

I am on the expo sdk 38.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it! The issues was that I needed to add `android.useNextNotificationsApi: true` to the app.json.
Then I had to do `expo:build` and **manually** upload the build.

Answer (score 1):

You have created your channel successfully but doesn't updated your app's expo notifications settings. For this you must add -

```
android: {
...
"useNextNotificationsApi": true
}
```

in your `app.json` file.

Then just run your code by clearing expo cache like -

```
expo start -c
```

And test it! You will start receiving the notifications on your Android 10+ mobiles also.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the documentation:

> If you create a notification and do not specify a channelId, Expo will automatically create a 'Default' channel for you and present the notification through that channel. If, however, you specify a channelId that has not yet been created on the device, the notification will not be shown on Android 8+ devices. Therefore, it's important to plan ahead and make sure that you create all of the channels you may need before sending out notifications.

> On devices with Android 7 and below, which don't support notification channels, Expo will remember the relevant settings you created the channel with (in this case, sound: true) and apply them directly to the individual notification before presenting it to the user.

So I think must be make sure somethings if you want to push to specify channel id:

- Your app run on devices 8.0+
- Channel create success on device without effect any setting from user (in case check you `gameupdates` channel)
- Take care your android app run on API 26+

Good luck.

Comment: The device is on android 10, the channel is successfully created (as I said, I can even find it as active in the notification settings on the expo app) and I am using the latest version of the expo app to test it. :(

Comment: _createNotificationAsync = () => {
  Notifications.presentLocalNotificationAsync({
    title: 'Reminder',
    body: 'This is an important reminder!!!!',
    android: {
      channelId: 'reminders',
      color: '#FF0000',
    },
  });
}

Comment: Did you create a notification with `gameupdates` channel?

Comment: Yes, my problem is that when I send a notification with the `gameupdates` channel id it never reaches the phone. Also, I am not using local notifications but sending from the expo tool.